# Jquery - Open a new window with content from the current page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a 'print' button to open a new window and display a PHP Variable in it.

The code below is looped through the PHP script as many times as there are tickets, however I can't seem to get the correct number to display when the window opens (the number that displays in the print link is correct - but when the new window is opened it's incorrect).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($) {
$('a.new-window').click(function(){

var recipe =  window.open('','PrintWindow','width=600,height=600');
var html = '<html><head><title>Print Your Ticket</title></head><body><div id="myprintticket">' + $('<div />').append($('#ticket').clone()).html() + '</div></body></html>';
recipe.document.open();
recipe.document.write(html);
recipe.document.close();

return false;

});
});
</script>

<a href="" class="new-window">Print <?php echo $EM_Booking->get_spaces() ?></a> 

<div style="display:none;">
<div id="ticket"><?php echo $EM_Booking->get_spaces() ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: if this is looped many times - you have many #ticket elements. ID of a html element must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

why not try something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="new-window">Print <?php echo $EM_Booking->get_spaces() ?>
    <div class="ticket" style="display:none">
        <?php echo $EM_Booking->get_spaces() ?>
    </div>
</a> 


<script>
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('a.new-window').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this),
            ticket = btn.find('.ticket').html(),            
            recipe =  window.open('','PrintWindow','width=600,height=600'),
            html = '<html><head><title>Print Your Ticket</title></head><body><div id="myprintticket">' + ticket + '</div></body></html>';
        recipe.document.open();
        recipe.document.write(html);
        recipe.document.close();
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

But much better solution would be to give a button a unique ID, and onclick open an existing (php-generated) page from the server passing that ID, e.g. `/getBooking.php?id=123` and that page would output whatever's needed.

Comment: Hi, That works perfectly! Thank you very much for such a quick solution :)

Comment: Just another quick question - when I put any HTML (ie <a href="123">123</a> into one of the PHP echoes it breaks the script and displays "undefined", how would I go about sanitising the content to avoid that?

Comment: @Meakin I'm not sure I understand the issue. Could you please post some code, e.g. with the html that is breaking your script? (or maybe start a new question, as this issue seems to be unrelated to the current one)